# Unable to label alphanumeric station names in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

[image: My region]I placed several stations sampled in the Long Island Sound using ArcMap 10.4.1. However, I can only label stations  which have only numbers in their numbers while those with alphanumerical names like E1, F2 etc do not get labelled.

| STATION | NUMBER | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| station A4 | A4 | 40.83 | -73.65 |
| station 6 | 6 | 41.00 | -73.85 |

[image: Attribute Table]

Comment: Add all this (and other) information to your original question, not just into comments (even when answering questions from comments).  Use the 'Edit' link below your question to update it.

Comment: What do you see in that column if you open the Attribute Table of that layer?  Do you see all the values that you expect to use as labels?  (Ie, not opening in Excel, but open as an Attribute table in ArcMap.)  Again, edit your question, and show a screenshot of the Attribute Table, illustrating the alphanumberic values in that table.

Comment: If your labels are based on the "Number" column than what you are seeing is expected because the "Number" column has NULL for stations that have alpha-numeric IDs.  So the question you need to ask yourself is how do you properly populate the "Number" column and then the labeling will work.

Comment: The table in your question wasn't rendering properly because it needed an empty line before and after it. It's fixed now.

Comment: @bixb0012 i am not sure I understood your comment. The Long Island survey had some stations which were alphanumeric and some just numbers. I cant change  that. So Arcmap cannot label alphanummeric? thanks

Comment: Your example table shows an example where "station A4" becomes "A4", but the screenshot of your table shows "Station A4" going to NULL.  Assuming you have labeling setup for the `NUMBER` field, a NULL will become an empty/missing label.  You need to fix your table.

Comment: @bixb0012 my apologies but I might have confused you. I created the column 'NUMBER' by removing the word 'Station' from the 'STATION' column as I thought this would give me problems with ArcMap. After creating my plot I opened the Layer Properties Menu -> Labels -> then in Label field i selected NUMBER. Are you asking me to change the 'format' of the 'NUMBER' column in Excel? Or else how do i fix my table as you suggested?

Comment: If you removed the word "Station" from the `Station` column in Excel than something is happening between Excel and ArcMap because the screenshot clearly shows the rows with alphabetic characters are getting converted to NULL and thus not labeling because there is nothing to show for a label with NULL.  Fix the issue with that column and the labeling problem goes away.